# The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in activity_main.xml

Tags: kotlin

[This is AndroidManifest.xml & you can see the errors down below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLXNO.png)

[This is what error i'm getting while run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7of2.png)

[It was working completely fine till now, I restart the pc, after that i opened android studio and find that main activity is not declared in activity_main.xml asking me to create a class while id didn't change anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXW1R.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow add your AndroidManifest.xml file also and please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MainActivity` is not included inside the `<application/>` tag of the manifest.

You can replace the code inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` with this one and it should work. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tiptime">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TipTime">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TipTime">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It's working now, Thank you.  :)

Answer (score -1):

From the `Build` menu, try `Clean Project` and then `Rebuild Project`

Comment: tried both, ain't working